# NoSuchMethodException trying to instantiate ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-mvvm

I'm trying to instantiate my viewmodel but I get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class
>   com.test.domain.PostUserTokenImpl]    at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
>           at com.test.presentation.viewmodel.LoginVMFactory.create(LoginVMFactory.kt:13)

I try to do an instance of my ViewModel which holds and interface

### view

```
private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginVMFactory(PostUserTokenImpl(UserRepoImpl()))).get(LoginViewModel::class.java) }
```

### LoginVMFactory

```
class LoginVMFactory(private val useCase: PostUserTokenImpl):ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(PostUserTokenImpl::class.java).newInstance(useCase)
    }
}
```

### LoginViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel(private val useCase: PostUserToken): ViewModel() {
 ...
}
```

### PostUserToken

```
interface PostUserToken {

    suspend fun postUserToken(user: User): Resource<Boolean>
}
```

### PostUserTokenImpl

```
class PostUserTokenImpl(private val repo: UserRepo): PostUserToken {

   override suspend fun postUserToken(user:User):Resource<Boolean> = repo.saveUserToken(user)

}
```

Any Idea why is this happening ? I suspect that is maybe because we cant instantiate with interfaces our viewmodels ?

Answer (score 0):

Changed my implementation to

```
class LoginVMFactory(private val useCase: PostUserToken):ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(PostUserToken::class.java).newInstance(useCase)
    }
}
```

and then in my view

```
private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginVMFactory(PostUserTokenImpl(UserRepoImpl()))).get(LoginViewModel::class.java) }
```